# Зачем глубокое понимание HashMap

Tags: java, коллекции

Не имею какого-то большого опыта в разработке, всего несколько лет, поэтому задам неочевидный лично мне вопрос, который в обычной жизни озвучивать как-то страшновато) Зачем на собеседованиях настолько жестко гоняют по HashMap ? Со всем остальным прям понятно, но зачем нам глубокое понимание того как она работает? В какой конкретный момент программисту надо прям понимание как оно работает? Прям жизненно надо понимать как происходит в неё вставка? Есть какой-то момент, когда у нас сильно просядет перфоманс из-за непонимания? Есть какая-то причина держать всё это в голове? Какие кейсы в прикладном программировании когда нам надо как-то жестко использовать хэмапу или хэштейбл что бы всем знать эти нюансы? Просто есть ощущение, что упускаю какую-то гигантскую часть жизни и весь мир использует хэшмапы как не в себя, при том что я за последние три года использовал их максимум раз 10 наверное, без каких-либо сложных кейсов.
И ещё, раз уж начал глупые вопросы. Почему исходники  той же хэшмапы настолько блин тяжело читать? Почему те же исходники спринга всегда прекрасны и понятны, но тут прям какой-то ад. Так сделано, потому что процессору быстрее этот страшный код перемалывать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще, я бы сказал, так:

1. Знание того как устроены кишки `HashMap` не является обязательной историей
2. Однако знание почему `HashMap` важен - это часть обязательной программы

Исходники `HashMap` это сущий адъ - соглашусь, не в последнюю очередь это благодаря тому, что его несколько раз переписывали - в частности в Java 8 он реализован через бинарное дерево, а в старых версиях это просто через список/массив.

Начнине с [версии для Java 7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java) - там код более читабельный.